# Run onFailure retrofit 2 in Signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, retrofit2

I used retrofit 2, okhttp and [moshi-jsonapi](https://github.com/kamikat/moshi-jsonapi) in android project.

Debug Build apk and application is correct, But I have error in build signed apk (release mode), I used `dontwarn` in `proguard-rules.pro` for pass the build signed apk, But my application in signed mode every time run onFailure from Callback.

**Throwable message:**

```
platform java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,a.a.a.j> annotated [] requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered
```

I never have used LinkedHashMap!

When useing `minifyEnabled false` signed apk and application is correct But it's not secure solution.

**proguard-rules.pro:**

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class okio.** { *; }

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }

-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to keep your Model attributes unminified. If all the models are in one package then you can use,

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.model.** { <fields>; }
```

or you have to use like the following

```
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;
```

I could not reply on comment with the following code...so just editing the answer.. do you mind trying this

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
@com.squareup.moshi.FromJson *;
@com.squareup.moshi.ToJson *;}
```

Comment: I using Moshi. Model attributes in Moshi is `@Json(name = "name")` and I used this in every model but not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it after use this code in proguard:

```
-keepclassmembers public abstract class moe.banana.jsonapi2.** {
   *;
}
```